# Proof that if bounded function $ f$ is integrable then $cf$ is integrable

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> I am supposed to prove that if bounded function $f$ in integrable,
>   then $cf$ is integrable, where c is constant and addiotionally there
>   holds:
>
> $$\int_{a}^{b}cf=c \int_{a}^{b}f$$

I know that I have to divide it as:

- if $c\geq 0$
- if $c<0$

But I do not know, what to do next.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried? What could you use to prove this?

Comment: @AlainRemillard I edited my post, but I really do not know, what to do next

Comment: Your first line is all that is required. Since $f$ is bounded, we know that an integral of $f$ over a bounded region is certainly bounded, i.e, is a real number, and $c$ is a real number, thus $c\int_a^b \! f$ is certainly a real number as well.

Comment: @K.defaoite thank you

Comment: just use the definition of the integral, it follows easily from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $~f~$ and $~g~$ be integrable functions from a bounded closed interval $~[a, b]~$
to $~\mathbb R~$  and let $~c~$ be a real number.

There is nothing to show when $~c = 0~$.

So, first consider the case when $~c \gt 0~$. Let $~P~$ be a partition of $~[a, b]~$. Clearly $$\sup cf([P_{k−1}, P_k]) = c · \sup f([P_{k−1}, P_k])~.$$
which means that $~U(cf, P) = cU(f, P)~$. Thus it follows that $~U(cf) = cU(f)~$. Similarly, we also have $~L(cf) = cL(f)~$. Then $$U(cf) = cU(f) = cL(f) = L(cf)$$
so $~cf~$ is integrable and $$\int_{a}^{b}cf=c \int_{a}^{b}f~.$$
Now to prove the case when $~c\lt 0~$, it suffices to consider the case when $~c = −1~$, since then for general $~c\lt 0~$, we have
$$\int_{a}^{b}cf=\int_{a}^{b}-(-c)f=-\int_{a}^{b}(-c)f=-(-c)\int_{a}^{b}f=c \int_{a}^{b}f$$
using the case $~c = −1~$ for the second equality and the case $~c\gt 0~$ for the third. Thus we assume that $~c = −1~$. Then its easy to see that $~U(−f, P) = −L(f, P)~$ for all partitions $~P~$. Thus

$~U(−f) = \inf\{U(−f, P)~ : ~P ~$is a partition$\} = − \sup\{L(f, P)~ :~ P~$ is a partition$\} = −L(f)~$.

Similarly, we also get $~L(−f) = −U(f)~$. Thus, since $~f~$ is integrable, we have
$$U(−f) = −L(f) = −U(f) = L(−f)$$
so $~−f~$ is integrable and$$\int_{a}^{b}(-f)=- \int_{a}^{b}f~.$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you so much